# Using pdfMake library i want to give my pdf a size of 6 x 4 cm

Tags: javascript, web

Hi I'm using pdfMake library and I'm struggling to give my pdf a size of 6x4 cm
For example I have
pageSize: { width: 595.28, height: 'auto' }
what should i write inside of width and height to give me 6x4cm? some help??

Comment: have you made an attempt (please share)? have you read the [docs](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/page/)?

Comment: I read this but for example pageSize: {
    width: 595.28,
    height: 'auto'
  }, what should i write inside of width and height to give me 6 x4 cm?

Comment: Yeah I did it works thanks But There is only one thing i want to know ? How can position my text at the right top of my pdf ? This is the only thing i struggled with ?Some help ?It would be appreciative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in [pdfmake's documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/), all units are in **pt**.

You need to convert your page dimensions from **millimeter** to **pt** :

```
const pageDimensionsInPt = pageDimensionsInMm * 2,83465;
```

Comment: Yep. I already solved this problem . Thanks for the answer anyway :)